# Why are images excluded from pdf file using mywindow.print()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My use case is as follows:

I have page with a print button. The page contains many info including receipts as shown below. When the use clicks "print", I want to print the receipts only:

[image]

Below is the code for my print button below:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" onclick="PrintElem('contentRecu')">
                        <img src="{{ asset('img/Print.png') }}"/>Imprimer </button>
```

Below is my javascript code for printing:

```
function PrintElem(elem) {
    var prints = '';

    if($(".contentRecu").html()!=undefined){
        $( ".contentRecu" ).each(function( index ) {
            prints += $(this).html() + ' <br><br> ';
        });
    }


    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

    mywindow.document.open();

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title>');

    mywindow.document.write('<link href="http://localhost/bill/public/css/bills_style_pdf.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css"></head><body >');

    mywindow.document.write(prints);

    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10

    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

    mywindow.print();

    mywindow.close();

    return true;
}
```

The code above successfully gets the receipts from the page as you can see below:
[image]

After opening the pdf file, only the receipt data is printed and not the image as shown below. why is that and what can I do so that the image is printed as well?

[image]

Below is my css (bills_style_pdf.css) for the image

```
div.wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
    height: 560px;
    min-width: 900px;
    min-height: 560px;
    background-image: url("../img/AES_Layout_A5.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: left top;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your entire content into a div tag e.g. `<div id="mycontent">` and add a style for that div. 
`#divmycontent {
        margin-top: 0px; 
        margin-left: 0px;
        background-image: url(your-bg-image.jpg);
 }`